# Remove Factor Variables from Fixed Effects Regression lm Object in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I estimate a fixed effects model in R using the `lm()` function. The fixed effects are included as `factor(FE)`. Furthermore, I include district specific time trends which are included in the model as `factor(distr):trend`. In total, this results in about 250 coefficients estimated. Since I am only interested in around 10 coefficients, I would like to remove the rest of the model object. Specifically, I would like to remove everything of these additional coefficients of the object. For further understanding, the current workflow is:

1. estimate regression using `lm()` - everything works well
2. compute HAC standard errors using `coeftest()` with `vcvovHAC` - computation takes forever for so many parameters
3. plug models into `stargazer()` and suppress all the not needed variables from the table - works well

As you can see, the problem occurs when computing the standard errors of the parameters.

To address several possibly upcoming hints/questions:

1. Why are you not using plm package?

- Residuals are somehow grouped which gets annoying in the process of model diagnostics. Also, afaik residuals are reordered somehow and cannot be merged with the data easily again

2. Why are you not using fixest package?

- It is not possible to use with stargazer.

I already removed the coefficients of the model using `model$coefficients`. Then, when using `summary(model)` the standard errors of the omitted coefficients are still shown and the coefficients are displayed as `NA`. Then, the problem happens again with `coeftest()` since the many coefficients are still present.

So, I would like to remove these coefficients from the model object entirely, in order to continue working with the object!

I am very happy for any hints on a possible solution!

Comment: please share your code and a snippet of your data so others can help. also why not remove the levels of the factors from your data before modeling ?

Comment: You could try using fixest in combination with another table-generating package such as modelsummary, or use fixest's own `etable()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching to solve the problem, I came to the conclusion that no feasible solution exists. I decided to use the `fixest` package and its corresponding `etable()` function and am very happy now. Can only recommend to use this package!